# Pass active record attributes in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, string-interpolation

I have a method, that takes an array of rails active record objects and sort those records based on the second parameter passed into the method. The method looks something like :

```
def sort_provider(providers, attr)
  provider.sort!(|a,b| a."#{attr}" <=> b."#{attr}")
end
```

When I call the method, `sort_providers(providers, "name")`, I get a `unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '('`.

How do I get the method to sort the array based on the second parameter passed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `send`

```
providers.sort_by! { |a, b| a.send(attr) <=> b.send(attr) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `attr` is a symbol:

```
providers.sort_by(&attr)
```